# Devise RPX Connectable error undefined method user_session_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rpx

I am trying to install the devise_rpx_connectable gem functionality into my application. Everything seemed to install fine but when I try to call

```
<%= link_to_rpx "Signin using RPX!", user_session_url %>
```

I get an undefined method error on user_session_url

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had messed up on the initial generation of the devise model. I backed out and re-did it and everything started to work.